# Displaying grid record in form by click event

Tags: extjs3

I have created a Simple Grid of Employee Records in Ext-js .In that i have added all the records statically .I want a code so that by clicking on any record , its detail information should be displayed in a form.How to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In theory. You need add event - cellclick. id get the record. create a form and put it in the required data)